# why i cant find data when using = but when use like it show up

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table `A` and one column name `nama_dir` datatype `varchar(50).`
i want to find this `2134882`
so i make a query

```
select * from table A where nama_dir = '2134882'
```

, i didnt get any result.
but when i change `=` to `like` and add `'%2134882%'` I got the data, can anybody explain why this happening? front and end of the data doesn't have a spacing. why i show up when I'm using `like` but no `=`

please help me

[image: Describe table]

[image: using trim]

[image: not using trim]

[image: using like]

Comment: could you give us image of your both try

Comment: please paste your query which is getting a data

Comment: Also try this: select *, len(name_dir) as FieldLength from table A where name_dir Like '%2134882%' -- Compare to the expected length

Comment: see my answer hop it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

May be there are some spaces, can you try `trim`?

```
select * from table A where trim(name_dir) = '2134882'
```

Comment: can u tell the output of `describe A`

Comment: Try `SELECT length(name_dir)  from tableA where name_dir LIKE '%2134882%'` to see if you have hidden characters

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps MySQL is treating your value as an integer, try removing quotes

```
select * from A where name_dir = 2134882
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write worng DIr name change **`name_dir` to `nama_dir`:**

```
select * from table A where nama_dir = '2134882'
```

if you use `=` operator then it's find specific value in table. it means in your table `2134882` this DIR is not available then data can't show you.

If you use `LIKE` operator then it's find value which available in `2134882`  this data.

- The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column.
- There are two wildcards used in conjunction with the LIKE operator:

---

- `%` - The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters.
- `_` - The underscore represents a single character

---

**like Operater :** WHERE CustomerName LIKE `'%or%'`

**Description :** Finds any values that have **"or"** in any position

Comment: which language for you can try ?? @jazz

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'Table' from the code. The correct code is:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE name_dir = '2134882'
```